# Printing from eclipse while in dark theme

Tags: java, eclipse, printing

When printing from a dark theme in Eclipse, my code is hardly readable because it keeps the same font color that is meant to go on the dark background.

Is there a way to modify the settings so that all syntax highlighting disabled when printing?

I have to regularly print my code for school (cause who cares about trees, right?) and don't want to keep changing my theme every time.

Thanks,
Jared

Comment: Are you saying that the background and text are black?

Comment: No, it is smart enough to change the background color to white, but it leaves some of the text white so it gets lost when printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the dark theme in eclipse has not a good default color settings, however, you can set your own colors for different things, go to `window -> preferences -> General -> Appareance -> Colors and Fonts` and then you can change colors as you wish.
I think the one you are looking for is `Outgoing change color` under `Text Compare` menu:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click the file and select "Open With" then select "Text Editor". This will just give you a plain editor with no syntax highlighting. Use the print function and this will print black on white.